# Adding a breakpoint in the middle of a line with Chrome Web Inspector

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, breakpoints, web-inspector

Say I have some JavaScript code like this:

```js
function breakpointInside() { console.log("How do I add a breakpoint here?"); }
breakpointInside();
```

Assume I can't edit the source file. I would like to debug `breakpointInside`, but I cannot figure out how to add a breakpoint in the middle of the line. In this example, it's trivial to step into the function, but assume it's a more complex script where this isn't as practical.

Comment: If anyone's wondering why, I'm trying to debug a minified script hosted on a server not controlled by me.

Comment: Since Google Chrome 55 you can get multiple breakpoints per line. Please have a look here: - https://umaar.com/dev-tips/129-inline-breakpoints/ - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HF1luRD4Qmk&feature=youtu.be&t=573

Comment: Use cautiously with large minified scripts as annotating the line with all of the breakpoint choices can take many minutes, effectively killing the thread.

Answer (score 21):

Here are 2 related solutions

#### 1) De-obfuscate Source

You can't put a breakpoint inside a line, but you can (in newer versions of Chrome) right-click on the script, select `De-obfuscate Source`, and put a breakpoint on the de-obfuscated version (which will have one statement on each line).

#### 2) Pretty Print

*(based on comment by Nicolas)*

In later versions of Chromium-based browsers, this function is called *"Pretty print"* and is available as a button at the left below the source code panel that looks like `{}`

Comment: In 2015 you can click the {} button called pretty print at the bottom left.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the source with Chrome DevTools live: simply double click on the source in the Scripts panel and add a line break before console.log. Press Ctrl+Enter or Ctrl+S to commit your change into the virtual machine. Then set breakpoint on the new line containing console.log.

Comment: I tried this before I posted the question with little success. Now that I try it again, I can get it to work on something slightly more complex than what's in my question, but not for the application I was actually going to use it on. When I try to use this trick on the real application, I can edit it successfully once. The new breakpoint does not work, however. If I then try to edit the script again, I get this error in the console: `Uncaught Script not found`. I'm probably going to go with Digital's answer since it works, but thanks anyway.

Comment: On further investigation it appears this error is from line 2344 of http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/debug-debugger.js.

Comment: I filed a bug on the live-edit issue: http://crbug.com/92134 We would appreciate if you attached to the bug a code snippet on which we could reproduce the problem and specify which Chrome version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

The comment by Nicolas Boisteault is the one to be used in latest versions of chrome.

> In 2015 you can click the {} button called pretty print at the bottom left. – Nicolas Boisteault